# OpenGL: are 16bit internal formats resembling Luminence + Alpha possible?

Tags: c++, opengl, fragment-shader

I have a luminescence alpha texture where each pixel has two bytes, the first byte is luminescence and the second byte is alpha.

Is it possible to upload this into the GPU such that (within the fragment shader) the alpha component will always refer to alpha, regardless of the texture used, without wasting texture memory for green and blue channels?

```
// fragment shader 
vec4 px = texture(tex, uv);
px.r; // is luminescence
px.a; // is alpha (note that .a is used, not .g which would be green for 32bit RGBA textures)
```

The reason I want to avoid using GL_RG as the internal format, is because this would require I use a separate codepath within the shader for 32bit RGBA textures, and I'd like to avoid setting uniforms / conditionals for different texture types.

(If common GPUs are able to eliminate memory overhead of the G and B channels if they're empty/redundant for RGBA internal formats, that would be okay too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The reason I want to avoid using GL_RG as the internal format, is because this would require I use a separate codepath within the shader for 32bit RGBA textures

The internal format defines the components stored in the texture. What you fetch however can be adjusted by using a [swizzle mask for the texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Swizzle). To emulate a luminance/alpha with RG, you'd do this:

```
GLint swizzleMask[] = {GL_RED, GL_RED, GL_RED, GL_GREEN};
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

Comment: Would I need to set the swizzle after every texture bind, or just once per texture when it's first uploaded?  (not sure if the swizzle state is in the texture or if it's global)

Comment: ah, I just tried it and it's texture state, and works exactly like I hoped, thank you!

Comment: @AnneQuinn: "*I just tried it*" Or you read the link I posted, and it makes it very clear at the top of that section that "texture parameters" are part of a texture object's state.